# Folder deletion error shutil.rmtree, file being used by another process

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to delete a folder and its contents, and then create another empty one, here is the error I'm getting along with the start of my program.

```
Players have already been created!
Overwrite old players?
yes
Are you sure you want to overwrite old players?
All data in DATA folder will be overwritten!
yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Character's attributes\Character's attributes.py", line 23, in <module>
    shutil.rmtree("DATA")
  File "C:\Python32\lib\shutil.py", line 283, in rmtree
    onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Python32\lib\shutil.py", line 281, in rmtree
    os.remove(fullname)
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'DATA\\Players.txt'
```

Nothing is open apart from Python, and I have tried this on multiple computers.
Here is this part of my code.

```
Y = "Yes", "yes", "Y", "y"
N = "No", "no", "N", "n"

try:
   with open("DATA/Players.txt" or "DATA/Strengths.txt" or "DATA/Skills.txt"):
       print("Players have already been created!")
       time.sleep(1)
       print("Overwrite old players?")
       answer = input()
       if answer in Y:
            print("Are you sure you want to overwrite old players?")
            print("All data in DATA folder will be overwritten!")
            answer = input()
            if answer in Y:
                 shutil.rmtree("DATA")
                 os.makedirs("DATA")
                 print("DATA folder has been overwritten!")
            elif answer in N:
               print("DATA termination aborted! Phew! That was close!")
               time.sleep(2)
               sys.exit("Exiting...")
       elif answer in N:
            sys.exit("Exiting...")
except IOError:
   print()
```

Help!

Update

I have replaced

```
with open("DATA/Players.txt" or "DATA/Strengths.txt" or "DATA/Skills.txt"):
```

with

```
with open("DATA/Players.txt" or "DATA/Strengths.txt" or "DATA/Skills.txt") as f: f.close()
```

And I ran the program (with data in the DATA folder), it worked fine and replaced the DATA folder, but straight after the replacement of the DATA folder, I got this error.

Players have already been created!
Overwrite old players?
yes
Are you sure you want to overwrite old players?
All data in DATA folder will be overwritten!
yes
DATA folder has been overwritten!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tristan\Desktop\Character's attributes\Character's attributes.py", line 35, in <module>
    with open("DATA"):
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'DATA'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tristan\Desktop\Character's attributes\Character's attributes.py", line 39, in <module>
    os.makedirs("DATA")
  File "C:\Python33\lib\os.py", line 269, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'DATA'
```

When I run it after without data in the DATA folder I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tristan\Desktop\Character's attributes\Character's attributes.py", line 35, in <module>
    with open("DATA"):
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'DATA'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tristan\Desktop\Character's attributes\Character's attributes.py", line 39, in <module>
    os.makedirs("DATA")
  File "C:\Python33\lib\os.py", line 269, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'DATA'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the:

```
with open("DATA/Players.txt" or "DATA/Strengths.txt" or "DATA/Skills.txt"):
```

to:

```
with open("DATA/Players.txt" or "DATA/Strengths.txt" or "DATA/Skills.txt") as f:
    f.close()
```

Comment: This makes no sense - the context manager makes sure the file is closed when the block is exited - having `f.close()`) inside such a block has no value.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are opening the file inside the directory you are trying to delete - they are then locked and mean the folder can't be deleted.

You seem to think that `with open("DATA/Players.txt" or "DATA/Strengths.txt" or "DATA/Skills.txt"):` will check for the existence of those files, which it won't do at all.

`"DATA/Players.txt" or "DATA/Strengths.txt" or "DATA/Skills.txt"` will evaluate to `"DATA/Players.txt"` (`or` returns the first `True` value, and non-empty strings are `True`), which will then be opened.

What you probably want is `if any(os.path.exists(path) for path in ("DATA/Players.txt", "DATA/Strengths.txt", "DATA/Skills.txt")):`

Your later error is probably caused by `DATA` being a directory - meaning that `open("DATA")` doesn't make sense (`open()` opens files).